# Change backgroundColor of react-native-calendars

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm making an app with react-native-calendars.

I want to change the background color of the calendar to blue.

```
<Calendar 
   style={{backgroundColor: "blue"}}
/>
```

I've tried the following, but the problem is that only the borders of the calendar change.

I want the background of the entire calendar to turn blue.

Please reply if you know a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ,

```js
<Calendar
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
        theme={{
          calendarBackground: 'transparent', 
        }}
      />
```

Set calendarBackground to your desired color

Answer (score 0):

If your background won't change, wrap your calendar with a `View` and modify the `theme` component in react-native-calanders, this allows you to access `calendarBackground`, and set it to the desired colour:

```
<View>
  <Calendar
    theme = {{
         calendarBackground: "*Your colour here*"
    }}
/>
```

Comment: You dont need to wrap the `Calendar` in a `View` to set theme